# Correlated evolution of discrete traits: do traits need to have phylogenetic signal?

Tags: evolution, phylogenetics, statistics

I'm doing a phylogenetic analysis using the Discrete program in [BayesTraits](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiFnpP4ysL8AhWlj4kEHXH6AasQFnoECA0QAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.evolution.reading.ac.uk%2FBayesTraitsV3%2FBayesTraitsV3.html&usg=AOvVaw0yqony3W9_I3KfXsOKGuqM). Of the  traits I am testing, one of them does not show any phylogenetic signal (using the [Fritz and Purvis d-statistic](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj1or2Gy8L8AhXuk4kEHU7RA2MQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2F20184650%2F&usg=AOvVaw1tPzuiuci0vsGnGGO25u_S)).

Does this mean that a test of correlated evolution using this trait is actually not appropriate? I was surprised that there is actually some support for correlated evolution between this trait with no signal and three other traits (Bayes Factors of 4-12).

Some of my colleagues, who know more about this than I do, think that Discrete analysis can be used if only one trait shows phylogenetic clustering.

I would be very grateful if someone could let me know whether or not this is the case, or point me towards any references for this! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a gut sense that you might be able to learn something even in the absence of phylogenetic signal in one of two characters. I don't have a reference, but I expect that simulations could sort it out.

I'd recommend using data of similar shape simulated on your tree to experiment with how frequently you would expect BFs of that magnitude even with independent evolution.

For example, you could shuffle the state of the non-signal character at the tips of the trees, and see how frequently you get a similar BF from Discrete. This is a heuristic Monte Carlo approach without a strong formal basis, but you could at least evaluate whether something about your phylogeny's structure is pathological and confuses Discrete. This Monte Carlo approach [is implemented in Mesquite](https://www.mesquiteproject.org/Pagel%20Correlation%20Method.html), providing some methodological precedent.

I'd also recommend running Discrete with MCMC rather than ML, if you have only used ML. For your actual trait data, I'd examine the rate parameters late in the MCMC chain using [Tracer](https://beast.community/tracer). If there are a lot of modes of the rate distribution, then it's possible that the internal reconstructions are too noisy to draw much of a conclusion.

I'd also consider whether you are encountering a multiple testing problem. How many total phylogenetic correlations are you examining? If the answer is "a large number of bivariate correlations", then you do expect to find what appears to be a strong association at some rate even when there is no association.

It would also help to know more about the size of your phylogeny and how the different characters look when mapped onto the tips, or on a sample reconstruction.